# Cannot setfocus to control after subform requery

Tags: vba, ms-access, setfocus

I have a simple form with a subform. In the main form is a field for the user to scan a UPC code. The UPC is found in the recordset then the subform is requeried to display the scanned item. The last command in the sub sets focus back to the UPC field in the main form for the next scan. Everything works except for setfocus. Tried decompile & C/R also imported all to new db.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rstManifest As Recordset
Dim strUPC As String
Dim strLotNum As String
Dim strCriteria As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rstManifest = db.OpenRecordset("tblManifest", dbOpenDynaset)
strUPC = Me.UPCScan
strLotNum = Me.LotNum
strCriteria = "[UPC] = '" & strUPC & "' And [Scanned] = False"

With rstManifest
    .MoveFirst
    .FindFirst strCriteria
    If rstManifest.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "UPC Item " & strUPC & " not found", vbOKOnly, "Try Again"
        GoTo Cleanup
    Else
        .Edit
        !LotNum = Me.LotNum
        !DateItemAdded = Now()
        !Scanned = True
        .Update
        Me!Manifest.Form.Requery
    End If
End With

Cleanup:
If IsNull(Me.LotNum Or Me.LotNum = "") Then
    Me.LotNum = strLotNum
End If
Me!UPCScan = Null
Me.UPCScan.SetFocus 'This line does not work
'DoCmd.GoToControl "UPCScan" 'Does not work either

rstManifest.Close
Set rstManifest = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the *RecordsetClone* and its automatic update of the form:

```vb
Dim rstManifest As DAO.Recordset
Dim strUPC As String
Dim strLotNum As String
Dim strCriteria As String

Set rstManifest = Me!Manifest.Form.RecordsetClone
strUPC = Me.UPCScan
strLotNum = Nz(Me.LotNum)
strCriteria = "[UPC] = '" & strUPC & "' And [Scanned] = False"

With rstManifest
    .MoveFirst
    .FindFirst strCriteria
    If rstManifest.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "UPC Item " & strUPC & " not found", vbOKOnly, "Try Again"
        GoTo Cleanup
    Else
        .Edit
        !LotNum = Me.LotNum
        !DateItemAdded = Now()
        !Scanned = True
        .Update
    End If
End With

Cleanup:
rstManifest.Close
If Nz(Me.LotNum) = "" And strLotNum <> "" Then
    Me.LotNum = strLotNum
End If
Me!UPCScan = Null
Me.UPCScan.SetFocus
```

or try:

```vb
Me.SetFocus
Me!UPCScan.SetFocus
```

Comment: Let me clarify: rstManifest is a table with 28K items. In this form, the user enters a lot number in one field then hitting enter moves to the UPC field. The subform only gets populated after a scan finds an item in the table which get updated as being scanned. So the form itself is not the recordset.

Comment: I see. You could use the _MasterLinkFields_ to filter the subform for the UPC. And/or first set focus to the main form. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Thanks... this is AfterUpdate code for UPCScan. The only other control is LotNo (tab0). When the scanner sends an enter action to the UPCScan (tab1) control, it performs the record changes to the table, requeries then changes focus back to LotNo which is normal.  I've tried your last suggestion, doesn't work. Since LotNo is required data (trying to scan when LotNo is empty produces a error msg), I cannot use OnFocus or OnEnter of that control to change the focus. I may just have to rewrite it differently.

Comment: Here's something interesting. I noticed that after the code ran, I could press tab and be back at the UPCScan control. Wanting to know what the active control was, I inserted code to determine the active control. Oddly enough, it was UPCScan, yet the curr was in

Comment: the previous control. I then inserted a SendKeys "{TAB}" after the the SetFocus line and it worked. While I don't like SendKeys, I'm going with it for now.